# Как сделать фильтрацию товаров?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть сайт [партнера.](http://www.technodom.kz/catalog/led_televizory) Слева вы можете видеть список фильтров по товарам. Со структорой БД разобрался и понял как она будет выглядить. Вопрос следующий, как собирать данные для php, которые отметил пользователь для фильтрации. Потом нажал кнопку применить, я получил эти данные в php, сделал нужные запрос к БД, получил данные и вывел на экран. Так вот, как все таки получить эти данные? я посмотрел исходные код, там вообще реализовано без форм?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', 'Селектор', function () {
    var id= $(this).attr('id'); //Записываем id товара
    $.ajax({
        url: 'filtr.php', //Указываем в какой файл отправить данные
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'id=' + id, //Указываем данные
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
});
```